# Is there major difference between Minikube and Kind?

Tags: kubernetes

I know Kind needs Docker, and Minikube needs Virtual Box - but for learning Kubernetes features are they the same?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use minikube; use docker desktop

Comment: they are different tools, but in the end, you have kubernetes inside

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In terms of learning Kubernetes features, they are the same. You will get the same Kubernetes and Kubernetes resources in both: Pod, Deployments, ConfigMaps, StatefulSets, Secrets, etc. assuming they both have the same Kubernetes version.

Under the hood they very similar too with some implementation differences.

- Minikube

  - Runs K8s in VM (1.7.0 vesion now supports running minikube on Docker)
  - Support multiple Hypervisors (VirtualBox, Hyperkit, parallels, etc)
  - You need to ssh to VM to run docker. (`minikube ssh`)
  - On the positive side, if you are using VMs, you get the VM isolation which is 'more secure' per se.
  - Update: It does support running in docker with `--driver=docker`
- Kind

  - Runs Docker in a VM (Part of the docker desktop installation for Mac, or Windows)
  - Runs Kubernetes in that "Docker" VM
  - Supports Hyperkit (Mac) or Hyper-V (Windows) hypervisors.
  - Has the convenience that you can run the docker client from your Mac or Windows.
  - You can actually run it in Linux with no need to use a VM (It's a docker native installation on Linux)
  - It runs all K8s components in a single container.